# How can I change code to select the user that I give it for input?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, bcrypt, bookshelf.js

I am trying to make a request and login but the function checks the first element from my users database. The problem is here 
var user = users[0]; how can I change code to select the users that I give it for input?

```
router.post('/login', function(req, res) {
    User.User.forge(
        {
        where: {email: req.body.email}
        }
    ).fetchAll().then(function(users) {
        if (users.length == 0) {
            res.json({success: false, msg: 'Authentication failed. User not found.'});
        } else {
            // check if password matches
            var user = users[0];
            user.comparePassword(req.body.password, function (err, isMatch) {
                if (isMatch && !err) {
                    // if user is found and password is right create a token
                    var token = jwt.encode(user, '123456');
                    res.json({success: true, token: 'JWT ' + token});
                } else {
                    res.json({success: false, msg: 'Authentication failed. Wrong password.'});
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Is it possible that your request return multiples users? If the answer is yes, the problem is not in selecting the user, but in your user schema

Comment: users - plural - might be an array correct? You want to check the password against every user in the array?

Comment: it select the first element of array everytime

Answer (score 0):

I've less than 50 reputations so I cannot leave a comment which would be the proper way to participate here.

Even if I'm not familiar with your syntax I don't think

```
var user = users[0];
```

is the propblem here. I guess the email is an unique property so why does

```
where: {email: req.body.email}
```

return a list with length > 1?
Do you use fetchAll() correctly or is there another method?

Comment: Just saw I made a nistake, sorry! What I ment was: var user = users[0]; is NOT the propblem here

Comment: Going with Wolfgang's suggestion: `User.where('email', req.body.email).fetch({require: true}).then(...`    Did you (Lupei) notice the [login_ example](http://bookshelfjs.org/#Model-static-extend) in the Bookshelf documentation?